# Java GUI specifying width of a textField

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextfield

I have a BorderLayout with layouts in the North, West and Center components. Here is my problem: I have a textField in my Center component and it extends the entire width of the it's parent layout.

It looks something like this...

```
===============================================================================
|                                                                             |
|                                NORTH                                        |
===============================================================================
|    WEST     |                  CENTER                                       |
|             | textField: __________________________________________________ |
```

I want to make it so the textField does not extend the entire layout but has a fixed size and is centered within the center component.

I have tried setting the preferredSize but had no luck. Code below...

```
  rText = new JTextField("1000"); 
  rText.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20, 10));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To center the JTextField, put it into its own JPanel, that uses the default FlowLayout and add that do the (I think) BorderLayout using container. To give the JTextField a good width, give it a column size when constructing it. **Do not** set its preferredSize as that won't behave well on different platforms. i.e.,

```
rText = new JTextField("1000", 10);
```

Comment: The flowlayout in combination with the column size did the trick, thanks!